# C# события. Событие при зажатой кнопке

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно что бы выполнялся некоторой метод при зажатой(не нажатой, а именно зажатой) кнопке "A". А когда я ее отпускаю вызывался другой метод.

Есть вот такой код. Но почему то мелодия проигрывается всего 1 секунду, а потом останавливатся.

```
 private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.A)
            {
                PlaySound();
                this.MyBotton.Background = Brushes.Black;
            }                
        }

        private void PlaySound()
        {
            wpalyer.URL = @"D:123.mp3";
            wpalyer.controls.play();
        }

        private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.A)
            {
                wpalyer.controls.stop();
                this.MyBotton.Background = Brushes.White;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `wpalyer` Это какой тип?

Comment: А какая реальная длина мелодии?

Comment: А попробуйте ещё выводить отладочную информацию (`Debug.WriteLine("что-то")`) внутри `Window_KeyDown` и Window_KeyUp`. Может быть, `KeyDown` вызывается чаще, чем вы думаете.

Comment: Или проверяйте [`IsRepeat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.isrepeat(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @VladD, я понял в чем проблема. Когда зажимаю A, то событие Window_KeyDown начинает зацикливаться. Добавил в Window_KeyDown Debug.WriteLine("что-то") и вижу как эти "что-то" плывут в окне Вывода. Как убрать данный цикл? Я думал может поставить паузу, но это считай костыль...

Comment: @VladD, я нашел способ как исправить данные зацикливание. Но можете посмотреть, мб есть более красивый способ?

Comment: @batya: Написал, гляньте.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо. Помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал такой путь:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.A &&
        !e.IsRepeat) // проверка на повторение
    {
        PlaySound();
        this.MyBotton.Background = Brushes.Black;
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил булевскую переменную `repeat` для проверки. Так как раньше событие при зажатой "A" начинала зацикливаться.

```
WindowsMediaPlayer wpalyer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();

bool repeat = true;

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.A && repeat== true)
        {
            PlaySound();
            this.MyBotton.Background = Brushes.Black;
            Debug.WriteLine("что-то");
            repeat = false;
        }           
    }

    private void PlaySound()
    {
        wpalyer.URL = @"D:\123.mp3";
        wpalyer.controls.play();
    }

    private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.A)
        {
            wpalyer.controls.stop();
            this.MyBotton.Background = Brushes.White;
            Debug.WriteLine("что-то из KeyUp");
            repeat = true;
        }
    }
```